How and why does Rust's Option<Vec<T>> get optimized to 24 bytes?
I was surprised that Option<Vec<T>> has the same size as Vec<T>:
fn main() {
  println!(
    "u128: {} -> {}",
    size_of::<u128>(),
    size_of::<Option<u128>>()
  );
  println!(
    "vec: {} -> {}",
    size_of::<Vec<u16>>(),
    size_of::<Option<Vec<u16>>>()
  );
}

evaluating to
u128: 16 -> 32
vec: 24 -> 24

So

How does Rust represent the None case for Option<Vec>? It looks like a normal Vec's 24 bytes come from 3 8-byte fields: a pointer, a byte capacity, and a length. My guess is that it's using a null pointer for None, but I'm not certain. Would Rust still be able to maintain the same memory layout if Vec held 2 pointers?

Why does Rust do this? For Option<u128> we clearly have the choice of using N bytes as long as N > 16, and Rust chooses N = 32. This of course has nice properties, e.g. we can access the ith element of a Vec<Option<u128>> with only bit shifts (no multiplications). But if that's ideal, shouldn't Rust make Option<Vec<T>> 32 bytes as well?


Rust version: rustc 1.83.0-nightly (1bc403daa 2024-10-11)

I would assume the Option<u128> representation is for alignment, not fast indexing.

"My guess is that it's using a null pointer for None, but I'm not certain" - you're correct. That's the null pointer optimization. In rust, there are types that can't be 0 (references for instance), and this last value can be used for instance by option to designate a last value. If you want this optimization on other types, take a look at std::num::NonZero and the crate nonany. For Option<u128>, u128 require to be aligned on 16, so if you use even just one bit of additional data, you'll jump to a 32bit value.

1. Option<Vec<_>>
You have discovered a niche value optimization guaranteed by Vec. More specifically:

Vec<T> contains...
RawVec<T>, which contains...
RawVecInner, which contains both...

Cap, an usize that can never exceed isize::MAX (known to rustc via rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end)
Unique<u8>, which contains...
NonNull<u8>. The documentation of NonNull specifically notes that the lack of NULL enables a memory layout optimization.



As a result, Option::<Vec<_>>::None is represented by 0 where the pointer would go (which is different than a valid instance of a NULL *const u8 pointer). Alternatively, it could be represented by a value exceeding isize::MAX where Cap would go. The other fields could be arbitrary for such a value. The compiler gets to choose which representation to use arbitrarily, but all zero bytes is be optimal for performance (easier to allocate).
I'm not sure what you mean by a Vec that held two pointers. Adding an additional pointer to Vec would increase the size of both Vec and Option<Vec<_>> by the size of a pointer.
2. Option<u128>
First, let's assume pointers are 8 bytes and the alignment of u128 is 16:
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<*const u8>()); // 8
println!("{}", std::mem::align_of::<u128>()); // 16

Consider the value vec![Some(0u128), Some(0u128)]. For soundness, both u128 values must be aligned. By your logic, the first item in the Vec must occupy at least 17 bytes (16 for the u128, 1 for the enum discriminant). The next aligned memory location (multiple of the alignment) would be 32 bytes from the beginning of the Vec. Because Vec doesn't have a way to add padding between items, the padding must fall within Option<u128>, making it 32 bytes. In fact, size is a multiple of alignment for all types.
In case you're interested, the closest thing to a 16-byte Option<u128> is an Option<NonZeroU128>.

But if that's ideal, shouldn't Rust make Option<Vec> 32 bytes as well

As I mentioned, it's an alignment concern not an indexing performance concern. Vec has an alignment of 8, so the size only needs to be a multiple of 8. If you were concerned with indexing performance, it's always possible to increase alignment:
/// Disclaimer: actual performance may vary;
/// consult your benchmark before making any optimization decision!
///
/// A 33% increase in memory usage will reduce cache locality!
#[repr(align(32))]
struct FastVec<T>(Vec<T>);


This answer does a pretty good job of showing how the current implementation optimizes the case of the Vec. However note that this is not simply an implementation detail but is actually guaranteed by the documentation: "Vec is and always will be a (pointer, capacity, length) triplet. […] The pointer will never be null, so this type is null-pointer-optimized."

Also more generally, the std::option documentation lists the basic types that can benefit from this optimization (even though the wording could be improved IMO)

I asked about if Vec held 2 (NotNull) pointers because I wondered if this generalizes. I suppose it would pick one NotNull arbitrarily to hold the None case. And perhaps having multiple NotNulls would enable storing a ternary enum { Foo, Bar, Baz<MultiNotNullType> } in the same size as MultiNotNullType?

@mwlon Thanks for clarifying! In theory, yes. In practice, no. Also note, due to Cap, you could support roughly usize::MAX - isize::MAX extra None variants without a second pointer.
